# turning 2 level predictor variable into yes and no for a regression model

Tags: r, dummy-variable

I have a question about a how to generate this variable: female and minority as one variable. If the variable female_minority means: the instructor is female and belongs to a minority group thus assign 1, otherwise it is 0.

My question is now how I can generate female_minority.
I have a dataset where I have the variable minority which is given with "no" and "yes". And I have the variable gender with "female" and "male". there are other variables which are not necessary.

model = ß1 + ß2appearance + ß3duration +ß4duration^2 +ß5ln(global) + ß6sex + ß7minority + ß8female_minority + ε

In plain pseudo code english:
if minority = yes && gender = female assign -> 1,
else 0

I'll need to do a regression based on this later.

Comment: `mydf$myvar <- ifelse(mydf$minority == "yes" & mydf$gender == "female", 1, 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Also with tidyverse/dplyr:

```
require(tidyverse)

mydf %>%
    mutate(ifelse(minority == "yes" & female == "female", 1,0))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).